# Trigger ECS Task from S3 Event

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

I want to trigger an ECS task when a file lands in an S3 bucket.  I tried using a Cloudwatch rules on an S3 event but it seems to require either a specific file in a specific location or triggers on file arrival in the entire bucket, no wildcards/prefixes/suffixes to control soemthing between those two extremes.

I've also tried triggering off of an SNS topic but can't seem to get the syntax right to work off my specifc topic.  Heres what I have so far:

```
{
 "source": [
   "aws.sns"
 ],
 "detail-type": [
   "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
 ],
 "detail": {
   "eventSource": [
     "sns.amazonaws.com"
   ],
   "EventSubscriptionARN": [
     "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789123:WCIS_ECS_Test:xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
   ],
   "TopicARN": [
     "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789123:My_Topic"
   ],
   "eventName": [
     "Publish"
   ]
 }
```

}

If anyone can help sort oout the syntax of this it would awesome, or alternatively, if there's another pattern I should be looking at, that suggestion would be awesome too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the tutorial on this link:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/

It basically answers your question how to process the specific file that was 
uploaded in your S3 bucket, into your ECS environment using a Lambda and a queue.

The tutorial might be a bit old, since it was written in 2015, but it still holds and you can use some optimizations, such as avoiding the shell script and replace it with the Python SDK for example, and/or use lambda step functions to do the calls to the SQS and ECS services.
You can also use a FIFO SQS queue for not missing any messages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The link is giving me a 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

You can try the option of S3 Trigger(preferable) or SNS trigger or SQS trigger to execute a lambda function. In your lambda function, you can use AWS Python SDK - Boto3 to run the ECS task based on your S3 file metadata.

Links - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html

Sample Code -

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ecs')
response = client.run_task(
    cluster='myCluster',
    taskDefinition='myECSService',
    count=1,
    launchType='EC2'
)
```